# button1_Click Windows form c# create scheduler task

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, buttonclick

I have an Windows form application in c# Visual Studio 2012 with a button_click on it. What I trying to do its the follow.
The application works fine, whenever I click on my button the application does what I am suppose to do. The problem its that I need to do this in a daily bases, and I am not going to be there to manually click the button my self. There's a way to automatically put a schedule to automatically starts the button daily? so I will leave the application opened all the time so every day at a certain time the button will be press.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Create a console application that is triggered by windows schedule, or create a windows service that uses Quartz to execute a job.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is centralize your event handler code into something like a class library.  Then your event handler can just call that centralized method.  Once you've done that, you can create a console app or windows service like L-Three suggested above.

```
// Event handler
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
      LibraryClass.DoStuff(...); // Pass whatever parameters might be needed
}

// In a separate project
public class LibraryClass
{
      public static void DoStuff(...)
      {
            // Move the code from your event handler here
      }
}

// In a console app
class Program
{
      static void Main(string [] args)
      {
            LibraryClass.DoStuff(...);  // pass whatever parameters are needed
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for your answer, this means that this cannot be done with a windows form? it only going to work with a console application? the problem is that my application is a web service client and I am consuming a web service. Thanks

Comment: This isn't the only way you can do it, but I would strongly recommend it over any kind of kludge that would involve clicking a button on a form based on some kind of timer.  There's nothing keeping you from consuming a web service from a class library either.  And if you centralize the code to the class library, you can re-use it in either a console app or winform.

Comment: @BenjaminArancibia Why does the fact that this is a web service client mean you need to use a winform application rather than a console application or a windows service app?

Comment: @Servy Hi, When I created I choose Windows form but it not mandatory to be like this. I choose to do it because the application is going to be used by others users without programming skills

Comment: @BenjaminArancibia Then this solution is exactly what you want to do; do the business logic in a class lib and expose multiple UIs for it, one that is easily automated and one that can be used by humans.

Comment: Again, as I mentioned, you're not going to have to make a choice between a console app or winform app.  You can still keep the winform app, and just use the console app for scheduled tasks.  If you centralize the code, you can make it work the same regardless of client.

Comment: Ok I get it now. I will try to do it with the console, I have never try it before but it seams to be a good solution. Thanks again

Answer (score -2):

Use a timer with an interval of 1000 and check if the current date has changed. Than do the "button click".

Comment: This is *extremely* fragile, and is not a very good way to automate something like this for something running for such a long period of time.  It means the code needs to be running 24/7, rather than only when it has work to do (meaning consuming system resources during all that time), restarting the computer will mess with it, the user can quite easily inadvertently close it, etc.  And that's not to mention all of the datetime issues.  What happens when someone changes the system clock, for example.

Comment: This is typically not how you do that.

Answer (score -2):

Hello Benjamin Arancibia, you can do this as follows:

In its App.config add a variables to hold the control when the task will happen.

```xml
<appSettings>    
    <add key="executeDailyService" value="true"/>
    <add key="dailyServiceTime" value="08:00-18:00"/>
    <add key="dailyServiceInterval" value="1"/>
</appSettings>
```

executeDailyService = Option to indicate whether the task will happen every day
dailyServiceTime = Option for specifying the period that it can happen here can customize eg.: 13:00-14:00
dailyServiceInterval = Option to inform the range of days which the task will happen eg:. 1 = every day, 2 = every other day ... n

When you start your application start the following method:

```
private void startTimer()
{
    // Loads the variables that will be used
    var executeDailyService = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["executeDailyService"];
    var dailyServiceTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dailyServiceTime"];
    var dailyServiceInterval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dailyServiceInterval"];
    // Validates that the variables are loaded
    if (executeDailyService != "true" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(dailyServiceTime) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(dailyServiceInterval))
        return;

    // Timer that controls the automatic execution of code
    var timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(dailyServiceInterval) * 60 * 1000; // Calculates how often will run your code
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(services);
    timer.Start();
}

private void services(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Loads of the variable time period
    var dailyServiceTime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dailyServiceTime"];
    // Validates the contents of the variable is in the correct format
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dailyServiceTime) || !dailyServiceTime.IsMatch("^\\d{2}:\\d{2}-\\d{2}:\\d{2}$"))
        return;

    // Calculates whether the current time is within the range you set
    var now = Util.Now();
    var dateBegin = Util.DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, Convert.ToInt32(dailyServiceTime.Substring(0, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(dailyServiceTime.Substring(3, 2)), 0);
    var dateEnd = Util.DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, Convert.ToInt32(dailyServiceTime.Substring(6, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(dailyServiceTime.Substring(9, 2)), 0);
    if (dateBegin > dateEnd || now < dateBegin || now > dateEnd)
        return;

    var timer = sender as Timer;
    timer.Stop();

    // You code here

    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: This is *extremely* fragile, and is not a very good way to automate something like this for something running for such a long period of time. It means the code needs to be running 24/7, rather than only when it has work to do (meaning consuming system resources during all that time), restarting the computer will mess with it, the user can quite easily inadvertently close it, etc. And that's not to mention all of the datetime issues. What happens when someone changes the system clock, for example.

Comment: @Servy completely disagree with you, you've used the Timer function?

This line:

timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32 (dailyServiceInterval) * 60 * 1000;

Will cause your code to run only when it is to run, he will not be running 24/7.

The .Net framework own has this control.

But another way to do this is to create a control console program and put the code in the main method. And then add the program in Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: The process will be alive 24/7.  It won't be actively consuming the CPU constantly, but it's memory footprint will be active at all times, making the potential for memory leaks very real, and it leads to the other problems I expaneded on; that the user can easily close it accidentally, restarts will mess with it, etc.  These are all direct effects of the fact that the actually process is running 24/7, rather than being scheduled by the OS via something like task scheduler or as a service.  `Timer` is designed primarily for shorter term intervals.

Comment: I agree with you, there will always be an active process, but this process is the own application process. Using the Timer does not create new processes.
The only process that will be active during the execution or during stop is the application.
In terms of usage of memory, only the application is leased it.
If you are processing a routine or asleep, will not change the consumption of memory.
In short the memory will always be leased the same size and what will change is the processing that will increase only when the process is active.

Comment: It would be extremely important to read about the Timer class: [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi all and thanks for all the replies. I would like to know @picossi, if your code given I need to insert it inside the private void button1_Click of before and insert the private void button1_Click on it? thanks

Comment: I know how a timer works.  Clearly you don't understand the implications of relying on a UI application to be running 24/7 in user mode when it's important that the user *not* interact/affect it in any way.  The application will most certainly be consuming memory even when waiting on the timer.  Even if the actual work firing regularly cleans itself up completely (although you're adding a lot of risk that it might not) you have the entire footprint of the UI that's being stood up and unused.

Comment: @BenjaminArancibia You're only setting yourself and your users up for a world of hurt and a ton of problems down the road by doing something like this.  You really need to take the time to pull out your UI if you want to run this as a scheduled operation.

Comment: @BenjaminArancibia Hi Benjamin Arancibia you must do the following, the code that is within your button1_Click method you should put on a method that puddle be accessed by the button1_Click method and other methods.
After you call this method on the line that has a comment: // You code here ... If you want you can use them as public methods.
They need not necessarily be private methods.

Comment: @Servy This may not be the best practice, but I'm giving a solution to his question.
Surely with this code it will get what they are wanting.
Now if this is the best way, that is, to use a UI application to automate routine is good or not good, that's another question.
You should try to contribute directly to the question and not vote negatively solutions proposed.

Comment: @picossi You're solving one problem and creating 10 more.  The OP will end up being worse off if he ends up using your solution.  He'll just be right back here in a few days trying to deal with all of the problems that this will bring him.  It's *not* irrelevant that this solution is extremely problematic, and it's *not* something to be discussed in a different question.  Answers need to not just answer the question, but answer them *well*.

Comment: @Servy Nothing against you. I looked your profile and you're a great programmer, sure knows what he does and what speech.
And I also agree with you that the application UI is not the best way to stay active 24/7.
But we should think about the following situation: and if that application is a legacy application that does not pay to be redone, or if this application is only temporary until you have another solution, or if this application is to run only a hazard and then will no longer run.

Comment: @picossi There's no indication at all that this is a legacy app to begin with, but even if it is, moving all of the non-UI code from a button click event to a console app should be very easy, regardless of the size of the application.  It doesn't need to be re-written from scratch just to strip out the UI.  Why would he go through all of the effort getting this working only to spend an equal if not lesser amount of effort just getting it working *properly*.

Comment: Hi, all I undestand the risk of doing that, but my problem is that I am stuck a bit of how of moving the UI code from a button_click to a console app. thanks all